# Counting Rows Prior to Another Row Value

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am working to find on average how many communications are sent to a lead record before they opt out of our communications for good. In our activity table, an activity type of 6 is a communication sent and an activity type of 9 is an opt out. So the table data may look something like this:

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| Lead Id | Activity ID | Activity Type | Activity Data |
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | 12345       | 6             | 1/1/2021      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | 12346       | 6             | 1/2/2021      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | 12347       | 10            | 1/3/2021      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | 12348       | 6             | 1/3/2021      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | 12349       | 6             | 1/4/2021      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1       | 123410      | 9             | 1/5/2021      |
+---------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I'm already able to find the average number of sends for records within a given time frame and I've tried to modify this query to account for the opt out activity through a subselect on the where clause. However, this doesn't bring up any results. This was based on the posting here: [How to count the number of rows before a given row in MySQL with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566266/how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-before-a-given-row-in-mysql-with-codeigniter)

```
    define macro counts
      (
    SELECT
      COUNT(CASE WHEN activity_type_id = 6 THEN activity_type_id END) as sends, 
      lead_id
    FROM data.Lead
    JOIN data.Activity USING (lead_id)
    WHERE activity_id < (SELECT activity_id FROM data.Activity WHERE activity_type_id = 9)
      AND activity_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-3-31'
      GROUP BY 2
      );
    
    SELECT avg(sends) as avgsends
    FROM $counts ;
```

For the output, it should count total number of "6" activity types only if they have an activity type "9" value and average them. So the function is looking to do multiple things:

a) Look for lead records who have an activity "9" value.
b) If they do, count the number of "6" values prior to the "9" value
c) Average the count across all leads in the given timeframe.

Comment: Provide desired output with explanations.

Comment: so you want to know the total no of 6 before first 9 appears right ?
input: [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 6, 6,  6], output: 6

Comment: @AmirSaleem correct. I just updated the post to explain a little bit better, but essentially a) Look for lead records who have an activity "9" value. b) If they do, count the number of "6" values prior to the "9" value c) Average the count across all leads in the given timeframe.

Comment: Okay, then what you can do is that you can get the Row where the first 9 appears. You can then use the ID of this row to fetch all the previous rows.

Comment: `SELECT LeadID From <Table> Where ActivityType = 9 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1`

Comment: To get the count of 6 prior to 9 
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <TABLE> WHERE LeadID < (SELECT LeadID From <TABLE> WHERE ActivtyType = 9 ORDER BY LeadID ASC LIMIT 1);`

Comment: I think you can implement the rest